# Management of photos for Django applications

Tags: python, django, upload, photo-gallery

My application uses a photo slideshow(diaporama). In the back-end management I would provide the path to the folder that contains the photos. How can I handle the management of photos  in Django?

Comment: Hi, would you mind posting a link to the docs of diaporama? Is it based on a flash player?

Comment: The diaporama will use a folder with photos. The management of the photos(photo uploading/deleting) should be done from Django admin. I think the implementation of the diaporama will be done in Javascript/jQuery. The important thing is to be able to handle the photos easily.

Comment: You're going to get a bunch of vague 'have you tried this?' answers until you refine your question. What does 'handle the photos easily' mean? Do you want to tag, file, search, crop, rotate, delete, share, etc etc? Write a proper spec of your task and then come back to SO with it.

Answer (score 4):

I would use [Photologue](http://code.google.com/p/django-photologue/):

Features:

- Complete photo gallery solution
- Manipulation functionality
- Fully inlcuded in Django Admin interface

Answer (score 0):

What about using the django filebrowser and reference your photos from the folders you upload to?
[django-filebrowser](http://code.google.com/p/django-filebrowser/)